# Why content within a header element can be accessed with .text and content within a p element with innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

If I have the following html

```
<h2 id="myheader">some content</h2>
<p id="myp">some content </p>
```

To get the content of the header, I can do

```
document.getElementById('myheader').text
```

But then I was trying the same logic with the paragraph element, but instead I had to use `innerHTML`

Is there some sort of logic behind this difference?

Also in the console I like the fact that I can write something like `window` and then I can drill down all the available methods that I can use after `window`. For example that's how I found what `window.document` is the same as `document`. Is there a way to do the same thing for things like `document.getElementById('myheader')`, a way to investigate what methods are available after the dot `document.getElementById('myheader').HERE` just to learn by experimenting

**EDIT: I realise that I am wrong about `.text`. There must be something wrong with my code (even though I can't see it), sorry for any confusion, if you think it should be edited not to mislead anyone, please do**

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? `.text` doesn't appear to be an available property in Chrome, at least. The properties that you should expect to be available are [defined as interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) by the W3C, such as [HTMLHeadingElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHeadingElement) for `<h1>` to `<h6>` and the generic [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

Comment: Im using chrome `Version 33.0.1750.152` and the element is a `<h2>` to which `text` workd

Comment: `var h2 = document.createElement('h2'); h2.text` gives me `undefined` in Chrome.

Comment: No just this `getElementById('myheader').text` works `myheader` being an `h2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is available for both elements (`H1` and `p`).

You can examine an HTMLElement like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(some_id),
    s = [],
    key;
for (key in elem) {
    s.push(key + ': ' + elem[key]);
}
s = s.join('\n');
console.log(s);
```

Many consoles create also a tree of the element structure just by logging an element:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(some_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you really do `document.getElementById('myheader').text`? Because it doesn't seem to me, unless you are using the jQuery [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

In any case, you can methods such as [`innerText` and `textContent`](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/) on both of your elements.

The reasons why `window.document` is the same as `document` is because `document` is a variable in the [**global scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), which **is** the `window` scope.

Also, to investigate which methods are available inside the console, you might assign your element to a variable, and then you can see the autocomplete, at least in Chrome developer tools.

```
var el = document.getElementById('myheader')
```

Then start typing `el. …` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, there's no such thing as a `.text` property on [`HTMLHeadingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHeadingElement). I've tested this on Chrome, just to be sure:

```
> document.createElement('h2').text
  undefined
```

To reliably get the text content from any element you can use this construct:

```
var text = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
```

Here, `.textContent` is understood by most browsers, whereas `.innerText` is specific to IE and `''` is the fallback value.